# Ignore multi tenant for specifics tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I am setting up multi tenant in an application with N clients. There is certain information that is common to all instances (for example, the roles that a user may have in the app). I want that information not to be duplicated in each of the tenants.

I am following this example: https://github.com/wmeints/spring-multi-tenant-demo, but the settings are applied to all tables.

How can I filter a request to apply this setting or not, depending on which table it refers to?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I can imagine more people have this problem. It is possible to do this.
You'll need to setup two data sources:

- A data source that is multi-tenant, as in my example.
- A second data "regular" data source.

In addition to this you'll need to create two JPA configuration objects:

- One that uses the multi-tenant data source
- A second JPA configuration that uses the regular data source.

Baeldung has a great tutorial on how to set up multiple databases with JPA that should get you in ths right direction: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases.